# Is windows 10 free for ever or just for an year?

Tags: windows

I currently have windows 7 installed in my computer. In my taskbar I am getting a notification. It says:-

```
                                  Get windows 10
                                 ------------------

Microsoft recommends upgrading to Windows 10. 
It's fast, familiar and free-and this PC is compatible.
Yes free! Full free version of Windows 10, not a trial. 

3GB+ Background download; Internet access fees may apply.
```

I am not understanding. I searched in google and in many websites it is written that it is *just free for 1 year*. Is the entire windows 10 operating free for ever or just for 1 year?

Comment: Once you upgrade to Windows 10 the license you receive is good for the lifetime of your machine.  The quoted text seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 was officially released on  July 29, 2015. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10):

> To encourage its adoption, Microsoft announced that during its first year of availability, Windows 10 would be made available free of charge to users of genuine copies of eligible editions of Windows 7 or Windows 8.1.

Microsoft recommends upgrading eligible editions of Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 while it is still free to do so. After July 29, 2016 you will have to pay to upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: it worth pointing out that everyone else during this first year has to pay.  So Windows 10 technically isn't free.  Microsoft is just offering the upgrade to those eligible users at no cost during the first year.  A nice way to think about it is that you have technically paid for Windows 10 through your purchase of the eligible Windows license or device.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade is free for 1 year. Once you have it installed it stays free.
People that upgrade after the 1 year free upgrade period is over, will have to purchase the upgrade from Microsoft.

Comment: Not quite right. It is free **until July 29, 2016**.